# Inactive community login redirect

Tags: community, force.com-sites

I have de-activated a community. However when I go to "All Communities" and click on the url for de-activated community it takes me to the main Experience Builder page of the community.

[image]

I have also added "page not found" for inactive site template. But it is still taking me to experience builder home page. please advise.

Comment: Does this happen only in one org? If you try the same with another org, are you seeing the same behavior? I couldn't reproduce the redirection to experience builder with a deactivated community in my org

Comment: Yes..I am seeing this issue in both UAT and prod environments.